# Google SC - is there any relation between Ave. CTR and Ave. Position?

Tags: ctr

Google SC - is there any relation between Ave. CTR and Ave. Position?

If there is one, then please could somebody explain the Google math with regard of position change for the particular query, within 2 days period as an example, thanks
[image: Day 1]

[image: Day2]

Comment: Your sample size here is only 2.  You aren't going to see meaningful correlation unless you look at a much bigger sample.  Maybe hundreds.

Comment: My question is not about that! The picture is the same for much bigger samples too!

Comment: Can you show a picture with a larger number of clicks and impressions?  Like one with hundreds of impressions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No, There is an average but rarely is anybody going to see the average. Currently a search on google gives these as the averages.

```
Position/CTR
1   28.5%
2   15.7%
3   11% 
4   8%
5   7.2%
6   5.1%
7   4%
8   3.2%
9   2.8%
10  2.5%
```

But if your title and description appear to meet the person who is searching better then they are more likely to click on your site regardless of position.

If you are getting more than 30% CTR at position 8 in the search result page ... you are killing it. Although you may want to look for a term with more impressions. The poor soul at position 1 with a zero CTR may try to improve his title and description.

"Killing it" as in doing very well. Beating the CTR of everybody else on the page! including the person who is listed first in the results. Under the situation of all other things being the same; The site listed first gets 28.5%. So getting more than 30% CTR you are getting more traffic than the person listed first would normally get.

The average CTR at position 7 is 4%.

Comment: Thanks, tell us more about "If you are getting more than 30% CTR at position 8 in the search result page ... you are killing it." I do not understand why it kills position?

Comment: @IVGSoftS thank you for your feedback, didn't realize it was unclear, I've updated my answer so that others would not need to read the comments to understand the reference.

Comment: Yes, that is the point, why the position doesn't improve then?

Comment: The position may improve over time. The CTR is a noisy factor and Google and other search engines don't rely on it to be dependable factor to change the position of a site in the SERPs... to easy for somebody to simply search and click on their own listing.

Comment: No it doesn't improve... So, in other words CTR is not a position affecting factor as it should be following logic. P.S. and it is not so easy to seat and click own links in SERP... Google track that well.

Comment: Sources of CTR noise come from everywhere ... say for instance CNN mentioned something and people went to google. They would click on what they believed as relevant. And in a few months that would no longer be what people are looking for.

Comment: It is not a noise... it is normal process....

Comment: @IVGSoftS I'm not suggesting it noise in your case ... but when google looks at a billion sites they see noise. So how much or little they want it to factor in is up to them. Currently I only use CTR to be better than the average ... If google wants to factor it or not is their call. But sometimes they do, but not by much.

Comment: @IVGSoftS I would suggest the factor is if a site is not performing they move it down ... not moving sites up based on CTR

Comment: I see... Google speculates as usual and goes against logic clearly shown above in my examples...

Comment: There was in the past search engines based on CTR. I love that algo as I always optimize my titles and descriptions and find a niche that makes my site stand out differently than the other 9 sites.  But if you consider terms like say the name of the president, well there is a lot of noise that google sees.

Comment: Yes, good time is over... pity to see that Google goes against the logic and is degrading... since there can't be any good search indexing service with no good content...